# Directory enumeration is missing csrss.exe and lsass.exe (c#)

Tags: c#, windows, enumeration, system32

I'm trying to enumerate files in `C:\Windows\system32` and `C:\Windows\SysWow64`. But I'm missing files `csrss.exe` and `lsass.exe` and possibly more, I only checked these two files.
Those files are there, I can see them in total commander and in explorer. They are just not in the enumeration result.

```
List<string> result = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\Windows\\system32", "*.exe", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));
```

I tried using `DirectoryInfo` instead of `Directory` with same result.
Also tried this:

```
List<string> result = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries("C:\\Windows\\system32", "*.exe", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));
```

And this:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Windows\\system32");
var result = dir.EnumerateFiles("*.exe", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Variable 'result' is not empty, but it doesn't contain mentioned files.

Framework version: v4.0.30319

Windows7: 6.1.7601 x64

Note: I know I can use workaround: `dir /a-d /b C:\Windows\system32` and then parse output. But I would like to avoid this.

Comment: Is your project 32-bit? If so your request for the system32 folder may be redirected to syswow64 which probably doesn't have those files. You can build for 64-bit or disable WOW64 folder redirection to see the real system32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) redirecting your request to SysWOW64, which doesn't contain those two executables (they're only ever needed by the OS, which will always run them in 64-bit mode).

When building your project as 64 bits, you should see those two files included in the results, assuming your process has sufficient permissions.

Alternatively, you can do a P/invoke call to [`Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before your `EnumerateFiles` call to disable file system redirection - just make sure to re-enable it when you're done.

The Pinvoke signature for this function is as follows:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);
```